# How to pass complex values (lists, dictionarys, ...) as args to python?

Tags: python, args

I would like to pass complex values as args to an python program

I use the regular approach to access args like `sys.argv[1]`. Called e.g. like `py .\test.py firstvalue`

What I would like to pass as an argument is not a simple value like the `firstvalue` from the example above. I would like to pass e.g. `[ {'transitiontime' : 322, 'off' : True, 'av' : [123,456], 'value' : 10}, {'transitiontime' : 533, 'off' : False, 'av' : [123,456], 'value' : 5}]` as **ONE** parameter.

Clearly I cant just pass it in quotes or s.th. else as an regular args value. Saving that complex value in an config file is not working either because it is changing on every launch of the python script. What would be a good approach for that?

Comment: They will always be strings, you have to parse them yourself

Comment: You could pass them as strings and then evaluate them using `literal_eval` from the `ast` module.

Comment: (Of the answers on the linked duplicate, the JSON one is solid advice if your lists are going to be generated by code in non-Python languages; `jq`, for example, can be used to robustly generate JSON lists from bash arrays, should that be where your data originally comes from).